# Cannot start service on virtualbox, system error 1053

Tags: c#, windows-services, virtualbox

I create two service in application:

1. FileSystemdriver, based on some.sys (sign driver) **(1st)**
2. Win32OwnProccess, based on some.exe **(2st)**

I use native code from advapi32.dll for working with services (for example)

```cs
[DllImport("advapi32.dll", EntryPoint = "OpenSCManagerW", ExactSpelling = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
    static extern IntPtr OpenSCManager(string machineName, string databaseName, SCManagerAccess dwDesiredAccess);
```

App works on my machine with win10.
But app**(2st)** cannot start on the VM virtualbox's with win10 from [Microsoft](https://dev.windows.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/windows/)(I didn't reconfigure it), giving to me system error 1053, by the way **(1st)** already started.

I try to add and increase by max value **ServicesPipeTimeout** in registry on VM, but it don't help to me. Then I try to create and start **(2st)** using **sc.exe**, but it don't help to me again. Then I try to create service Win32OwnProccess based on **iexplore.exe** and I again can't start this service. By the way some other standart(pre-installed) services I can start/stop.

Someone can tell me why I cann't start service on vitrualbox VM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my mistake.

For run my app was needed redistributable vs2013 **(1)** and vs2012 **(2)**, but I thought that for run was needed only **(1)**, which was installed on VM without **(2)**, that the was a mistake.